# How do I open the WhatsApp application with a message to a phone number on an Android device with Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, whatsapp

I'm building an app with a small feature that lets users communicate with each other via WhatsApp. Ideally, the app should directly launch the external WhatsApp application (if the user has it installed and the url is launchable, otherwise open SMS). My current approach works fine on iOS, but not on my Android device. I believe the issue comes from the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Can anybody help?

Here is the `launchWhatsApp` method implementation. Originally, I had not defined a `LaunchMode`, and so the app launched the web browser to WhatsApp's website. I spent several hours Googling how to directly launch the WhatsApp app before I realized I just needed to set the mode to `LaunchMode.externalApplication`. However, this only worked for iOS and not Android.

```
 // using url_launcher version: ^6.1.7
 Future<void> launchWhatsApp({required BuildContext context, required String phoneNumber}) async {
    // Phone number is in country code + number format (+11234567890)
    var androidUrlString = "https://whatsapp://send?phone=$phoneNumber&text=${Uri.parse('')}";
    var androidUrl = Uri.parse(androidUrlString);
    var iosUrlString = "https://wa.me/$phoneNumber?text=${Uri.parse('')}";
    var iosUrl = Uri.parse(iosUrlString);
    var smsUrl = Uri(scheme: 'sms', path: phoneNumber);

    // Will attempt to launch SMS message if the each platform's url cannot be launched ...
    // Show snackbar error if failed
    try {
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        if (await canLaunchUrl(iosUrl)) { 
          await launchUrl(iosUrl, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication); // WORKS HERE
        } else {
          await launchUrl(smsUrl);
        }
      } else {
        if (await canLaunchUrl(androidUrl)) { 
          await launchUrl(androidUrl, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication); // DOES NOT WORK
        } else {
          await launchUrl(smsUrl);
        }
      }
    } on Exception {
      showSnackbar(context, SnackBarError.unknownError);
      return;
    }
  }
```

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml file. Not sure what all should be private, so I only included snippets that I copy pasted from Google. Something tells me this is where the issue is.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.bundle.id">
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    ...
```

I got a new Android phone just for testing my Flutter app, specifically the WhatsApp functionality. I have barely configured it and not sure if this could be the root of the issue.

Comment: Try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72630463/13997210) hope its help to you.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, you will need to add a package reference to your AndroidManifest.xml like this. This will tell the operating system that your app would like to access another app with the specified package name (in this case WhatsApp).

Here is a link to the [documentation of the `<queries>`-element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/queries-element).

```
<queries>
  <package android:name="com.whatsapp" /> 
  // ... Rest of your queries
</queries>
```